# Django form.is_valid() False

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to create custom user authentication using any of email/phone to login.
When I use email it goes fine, but when I'm trying to enter with phone number nothing happens.
Error appears in views.py (form is not valid):

```
def login_request(request):
    user = request.user
    if user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect("account:home")
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AccountAuthenticationForm(request.POST)
        print('line 28 views', request.POST)
        **print('line 29 views', form.is_valid()) **
        if form.is_valid():
            email = request.POST['email']
            print('line 31 email:', email)
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=email, password=password) #or authenticate(phone=email, password=password)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                print('fine')
                return redirect("account:home")
            else:
                print(user, 'line38')
    form = AccountAuthenticationForm()
    return render(request, "account/login.html", {"login_form": form})
```

models.py

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

forms.py

```
class AccountAuthenticationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email = forms.CharField(label='Email or phone number')

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password',)

    def clean(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            email = self.cleaned_data['email']
            password = self.cleaned_data['password']
            print('line 48', email, password)
            if not authenticate(username=email, password=password):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid login")
```

backends.py

```
class EmailBackend(ModelBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None, **kwargs):
        try: #to allow authentication through phone number or any other field, modify the below statement
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(Q(email=username) | Q(phone=username))
            print('line 12', username, 'username')
            print('line 13', user)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            CustomUser().set_password(password)
        except MultipleObjectsReturned:
            return CustomUser.objects.filter(email=username).order_by('id').first()
        else:
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                print('line 20 backends.py', user)
                return user

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

settings.py has
`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('account.backends.EmailBackend',)`

these lines in backends.py

```
            if user.check_password(password) and self.user_can_authenticate(user):
                print('line 20 backends.py', user)
                return user
```

return correct user object in both cases, but for some reason when I use email (root@root.com) it works, but when I use phone number (+XXX...), it doesn't work.

Comment: Please recode the forms.py file and use function with forms.Form and set the 'required'=False for every form field.

Comment: unfortunately nothing changed

Comment: What is the logs of `print(form.errors)` after `is_valid()` was called?

Comment: ````line 30 views <ul class="errorlist"><li>email<ul class="errorlist"><li>Enter a valid email address.</li></ul></li></ul>
````

Answer (score 0):

Finally solve it!

Edited models.py
before

```
USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
```

after

```
USERNAME_FIELD = "email" or 'phone'
```

Then edited forms.py
before

```
class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('email', 'password',)
```

after

```
class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'password',)
```

Please take your attention, that I've had to change all custom variables name from 'email' to 'username'. IDK, but it worked for me.
Thanks everybody for help!